# Skype keeps disconnecting on OSX

Tags: macos, skype, osx-yosemite, homebrew

I'm having a problem with Skype on OS X Yosemite..

after logging in Skype it keeps disconnecting... I've tried it on 2 different Macs... on multiple different networks...

So basically the problem is not machine or network specific...
both installations of Skype are done via `brew cask install skype`

Here is the Console.app logs where skype disconnects

```
6/3/15 7:44:28.452 PM Skype[32534]: -[BASkype stopObservingLocalUser]: cannot get contact for current account (null)
6/3/15 7:44:35.355 PM Skype[32534]: An instance 0x60000086f680 of class SKContact was deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it. Current observation info: <NSKeyValueObservationInfo 0x608000c59b60> (
<NSKeyValueObservance 0x6080004df560: Observer: 0x6000002e9e80, Key path: moodMessage, Options: <New: NO, Old: NO, Prior: NO> Context: 0x101db8fe8, Property: 0x608000056fe0>
<NSKeyValueObservance 0x6080004c42f0: Observer: 0x6000002e9e80, Key path: avatarImageData, Options: <New: NO, Old: NO, Prior: NO> Context: 0x101db8fe8, Property: 0x600000a4b310>
<NSKeyValueObservance 0x6080004cf110: Observer: 0x6000002e9e80, Key path: CONTACT_PROFILE_TIMESTAMP, Options: <New: NO, Old: NO, Prior: NO> Context: 0x101db8fe8, Property: 0x60000084f8a0>
)
6/3/15 7:44:35.380 PM Skype[32534]: (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8eaed03c __exceptionPreprocess + 172
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff974be76e objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8eaeceed +[NSException raise:format:] + 205
    3   Foundation                          0x00007fff8e6896fe NSKVODeallocate + 293
    4   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff974d189c _ZN11objc_object17sidetable_releaseEb + 236
    5   Skype                               0x000000010029a5e9 Skype + 2729449
    6   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff974bcae8 _ZL27object_cxxDestructFromClassP11objc_objectP10objc_class + 127
    7   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff974b7637 objc_destructInstance + 119
    8   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff974b7595 object_dispose + 22
    9   AppKit                              0x00007fff88e24dec -[NSResponder dealloc] + 139
    10  AppKit                              0x00007fff8909ca03 -[NSViewController dealloc] + 433
    11  AppKit                              0x00007fff89193464 -[NSCollectionViewItem dealloc] + 84
    12  Skype                               0x000000010026f434 Skype + 2552884
    13  Skype                               0x0000000100295818 Skype + 2709528
    14  Skype                               0x00000001003217d2 Skype + 3282898
    15  Foundation                          0x00007fff8e689637 NSKVODeallocate + 94
    16  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff974d189c _ZN11objc_object17sidetable_releaseEb + 236
    17  AppKit                              0x00007fff88f08207 -[NSViewController release] + 133
    18  AppKit                              0x00007fff8909d588 -[NSAutounbinder dealloc] + 51
    19  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff974d189c _ZN11objc_object17sidetable_releaseEb + 236
    20  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff974b7e8f _ZN12_GLOBAL__N_119AutoreleasePoolPage3popEPv + 575
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8e9c36f2 _CFAutoreleasePoolPop + 50
    22  Foundation                          0x00007fff8e600762 -[NSAutoreleasePool drain] + 153
    23  AppKit                              0x00007fff88e25cc1 -[NSApplication run] + 800
    24  AppKit                              0x00007fff88da2354 NSApplicationMain + 1832
    25  Skype                               0x000000010001b41f Skype + 111647
    26  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff974ac5c9 start + 1
    27  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)

6/3/15 7:44:35.395 PM Skype[32534]: *** -[NSAutoreleasePool drain]: This pool has already been drained, do not release it (double release).
```

## Update

I've uninstalled skype and reinstalled it **via** .dmg package **not** `brew cask install`

and I keep getting the following error (from the console.app)... I'm not sure if it's identical to the previous or not, so I'm adding it also...

```
6/3/15 9:40:12.855 PM Skype[35034]: -[BASkype stopObservingLocalUser]: cannot get contact for current account (null)
6/3/15 9:40:12.918 PM Skype[35034]: An instance 0x10ceb6130 of class SKContact was deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it. Current observation info: <NSKeyValueObservationInfo 0x10f51bda0> (
<NSKeyValueObservance 0x10cee1d70: Observer: 0x102b40ed0, Key path: moodMessage, Options: <New: NO, Old: NO, Prior: NO> Context: 0x101e2db70, Property: 0x10fa86dd0>
<NSKeyValueObservance 0x10cebed40: Observer: 0x102b40ed0, Key path: avatarImageData, Options: <New: NO, Old: NO, Prior: NO> Context: 0x101e2db70, Property: 0x10e3e2ca0>
<NSKeyValueObservance 0x10cecbce0: Observer: 0x102b40ed0, Key path: CONTACT_PROFILE_TIMESTAMP, Options: <New: NO, Old: NO, Prior: NO> Context: 0x101e2db70, Property: 0x10eff2960>
)
6/3/15 9:40:12.919 PM Skype[35034]: (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8eaed03c __exceptionPreprocess + 172
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff974be76e objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8eaeceed +[NSException raise:format:] + 205
    3   Foundation                          0x00007fff8e6896fe NSKVODeallocate + 293
    4   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff974d189c _ZN11objc_object17sidetable_releaseEb + 236
    5   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8e9a1db0 CFRelease + 304
    6   libcache.dylib                      0x00007fff958c0047 _value_entry_remove + 128
    7   libcache.dylib                      0x00007fff958bf11f _entry_remove + 188
    8   libcache.dylib                      0x00007fff958bf286 _cache_remove_all_locked + 71
    9   libcache.dylib                      0x00007fff958bf487 cache_release + 162
    10  libcache.dylib                      0x00007fff958bf506 cache_destroy + 9
    11  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8ea88ea4 -[NSCache dealloc] + 36
    12  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff974d189c _ZN11objc_object17sidetable_releaseEb + 236
    13  Skype                               0x00000001014f95f4 Skype + 21992948
    14  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff974bcae8 _ZL27object_cxxDestructFromClassP11objc_objectP10objc_class + 127
    15  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff974b7637 objc_destructInstance + 119
    16  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff974b7595 object_dispose + 22
    17  Skype                               0x00000001014f5f8b Skype + 21979019
    18  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff974d189c _ZN11objc_object17sidetable_releaseEb + 236
    19  Skype                               0x000000010153d9c2 Skype + 22272450
    20  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff974d189c _ZN11objc_object17sidetable_releaseEb + 236
    21  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff974b7e8f _ZN12_GLOBAL__N_119AutoreleasePoolPage3popEPv + 575
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8e9c36f2 _CFAutoreleasePoolPop + 50
    23  Foundation                          0x00007fff8e62b45b __NSFireDelayedPerform + 428
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8ea402e4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 20
    25  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8ea3ff73 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 1059
    26  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8eab353d __CFRunLoopDoTimers + 301
    27  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8e9fb608 __CFRunLoopRun + 2024
    28  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8e9fabd8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
    29  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff8e30c56f RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 235
    30  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff8e30c2ea ReceiveNextEventCommon + 431
    31  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff8e30c12b _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 71
    32  AppKit                              0x00007fff88e309bb _DPSNextEvent + 978
    33  AppKit                              0x00007fff88e2ff68 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 346
    34  AppKit                              0x00007fff88e25bf3 -[NSApplication run] + 594
    35  AppKit                              0x00007fff88da2354 NSApplicationMain + 1832
    36  Skype                               0x000000010001b4ee Skype + 111854
    37  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff974ac5c9 start + 1
    38  ???                                 0x0000000000000002 0x0 + 2
)
```

I'm not sure if this question should be posted here or on different StackExchange site...

Comment: You are running the current version of Skype for OS X?

Comment: yeah... the current version is 7.7(335) and after each login... it works but for not more than 5 mins.

Comment: [7.8](http://blogs.skype.com/2015/05/27/skype-7-8-for-mac-is-now-available) is the current version on OS X and there was a crash big dealing with a character message but that wasn't suppose to effect OS X or was reported as not being effected so I would still update just incase it is

Comment: upgraded to skype Version 7.8 (391), but I got the same error...

Comment: I've uninstalled Skype ... then reinstalled it via .dmg package instead of brew cask install... but I get the same error ?!